# Promotion Not Opening from HMC: de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloSystemException: Cannot create Jalo instance for item

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

When I try to open promotions on HMC it throw this error,
first Couldn't understand problem and cause of problem?

Try to clear cookies, login/logout, restart browser as well -looks nothing works. (check this link for more detail, can't find anything
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12761785/promotion-not-opening-from-hmc.html )

Try to check this: ( https://answers.sap.com/questions/12750795/cannot-create-jalo-instance-for-item-due-to-null-d.html?childToView=12798465#answer-12798465 ) clearing orphan type helps sometime.

If any one can guide how to solve this issue and explain cause of this issue.

> Promotion Not Opening from HMC: Unhandled Exception:
>   de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloSystemException: Cannot create Jalo
>   instance for item 000000 due to null

[image]

Comment: Pls add some more details to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57867719/edit)

Comment: Hi @AjayPandya, I think i try my best to add details, if you want to know anything particular explain me i will try to add more, but all i tried to look into promotions on hmc and i got this error (many time go through this error, automatically works fine after sometime- can not understand root cause). if you can guide :)

Comment: I'm not sure about but this reference may give you some [hint](https://answers.sap.com/answers/12798465/view.html) 

Comment: yes removing orphan type helps sometimes but still couldn't understand cause of this problem! why it's occurring frequently ?

Comment: Have you been deleting custom Types?

Comment: I tried it, it works but whats cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`JaloSystemException` is the mother of all `Runtime` *exceptions* in *Hybris*. So, the exception alone is not very informative. 
The following comment i.e.

> Cannot create Jalo instance for item

suggests that *Hybris* is trying to create an instance of a custom type, the definition of which (in `items.xml`) does not exist anymore. Either the definitions were removed manually or they were lost during system migration.
Ideally, deleting orphans should resolve this.
If you are still getting the error after removing the orphan types then -

1. Either there is some legacy code that is trying to create an instance of the custom types, most probably through a factory, otherwise, it would have given a compilation error during build itself.

   2. The deleted custom type had a relation with the existing types, probably with the Promotion.

The ultimate solution is to run `initialize` on your local.

**Be very careful while running `initialize` as it will remove all the data from your system.